# DELPHI XE wpf like GUI

Tags: wpf, delphi, delphi-xe

I have an old Delphi app that i want to upgrade to delphi xe (always win 32).
Another request is to review a little bit the GUI to make it a little more "WPF like"

Is there any skinning tool out there or any tecnique you'll suggest to helo in doing that?

Comment: I'm guessing that your old app dates back to Delphi 6 or earlier and so is not using visual styles. Once it comes through to XE and starts using the modern themed look that will likely suffice.

Comment: @Paul-Jan: "WPF's emphasis on vector graphics allows most controls and elements to be scaled without loss in quality or pixelization, thus increasing accessibility." (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation), something which is not available in Delphi Win32 out of the box

Answer (score 1):

If you need just to make your applications looks different and modern without modifying the code, you can use skinning library like [VCLSkin](http://www.link-rank.com/), which will make your applications looks attractive with just one component dropped on your application.

[image]

but if you can replace your standard Delphi components with more advanced one, you can use library like [VGScense](http://www.ksdev.com/vgscene/index.html) which will make your application more like WPF looks

[image]

Comment: I guess it all comes down to taste but I find these revolting! What's wrong with fitting in to the native platform theme?

Comment: +1 to @David Heffernan. The Windows aero UI is great, and native aero apps look great on a Windows desktop. On its own, the first UI Mohammed showed above looks terrible to me, whereas the second is almost OK.

Comment: When used in a Remote Desktop Session a UI like the 2nd will creates lot's of traffic and will possibly be very slow when there's limited bandwidth.

Comment: @David Heffernan,@Andreas Rejbrand, I agree with you, but some applications will require different looks like Media players or games, also not all clients usually have the latest windows OS, so most of developers who looking for skinning libraries need them for older windows, but I prefer the native windows looks for my applications.

Comment: @Mohammed I've always found it funny that music players (e.g. Winamp) feel the need to look so different.

Comment: Generally, I *hate* skinned media players! I couldn't stand the Windows Media Player of Windows XP. Fortunately, the Windows Media Player of Windows 7 looks like a normal Windows application.

Comment: @Andres Win7 WMP is better but it still uses some rather odd UI idioms and takes a bit of getting used to. Winamp is the exemplar of how not to design UI!

Comment: @Mohammed What does your app do? Is it a media player or a game?

Comment: Always happens. First, look for skinning lib. Next, come back for solution of endless problems caused by it.

Comment: @David Heffernan,Nope, mostly Database applications and Accounting.

Comment: @Mohammed sounds like someone in your org has swallowed a book of trendy acronyms!

Comment: @Remko RDP performance optimizations are not hard to implement - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2010/02/27/optimizing-visual-studio-2010-and-wpf-applications-for-remote-desktop.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The current Delphi Version (XE2) has a new framework called FireMonkey.
This is vector based and uses hardware acceleration.
You can also use skins with firemonkey.